# iOS, detect ad-hoc from code

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to use a different API url for my iPhone app when I'm debugging or doing an ad-hoc deployment. Is there any way to detect from code (if adhoc) use this Url rather than the default one?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of:

1.) Conditional Compilation

Since you have to "Archive" the product to distribute the adhoc build, you might as well setup a new config for Archive and leverage the preprocessor.

2.) Alternate default .settings files based on Release/Debug/AdHoc.

Same suggestion as above, but using a .settings file instead of compilation. Personally, I'd recommend this over the conditional compilation because it can be changed (and saved) after deployment if you want to test other environments without redeploying.

**EDIT**

`Conditional Compilation refers to using "ifdef" blocks right? I tried this once but couldn't get it to check for AD-HOC, only DEBUG seemed to work`

Correct.

There is not an "ADHOC" macro defined by default. But you can easily add one.

Here's how you might go about setting up an additional configuration with a new preprocessor macro for your ADHOC builds:

**Step 1:** Setup a new Config (optional... you might just use Release... up to you).

[image: Setup a new config]

**Step 2:** Add the preprocessor macro for that config. In my screenshot it only shows Debug and Release because I didn't actually add a new config. If you added a new Config (and called it something like "AdHoc", it should show up here as well:

[image]

Add `ADHOC=1` just like the `DEBUG=1` macro for the debug config.

**Step 3:** Either modify your current Scheme, or duplicate it, such that the "Archive" step uses your new configuration:

[image]

Comment: I've not read/heard about either of these techniques. Do you have links? Conditional Compilation refers to using "ifdef" blocks right? I tried this once but couldn't get it to check for AD-HOC, only DEBUG seemed to work.

Comment: Excellent screenshots. Thank you. Everyone vote this answer up.

Comment: This is perfect. But I'm wondering if theres a way to modify Xcode templates so every new project comes with the new custom config and build settings?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this technique relies on you making sure you select the correct scheme before archiving - you could easily archive the Ad-Hoc build and submit to the app store, or would the different provisioning profiles stop the app submission from working?

Comment: @Willshaw - the archive action uses the archive scheme.  However, Steve, I don't see how this technique will differentiate between builds intended for the AppStore and builds intended for AdHoc distribution. It seems like what this is really distinguishing between is an ordinary Release build and an Archive release build. yeah ?

Comment: @Steve could you update this answer to reflect the newest version of XCode?