# Is there a preprocessor flag for Ad-Hoc builds?

Tags: c, xcode, macros, c-preprocessor

I commonly use the `DEBUG` preprocessor flag. But I've recently figured out that Ad-hoc and Store builds both use the release configuration. Is there a preprocessor flag that's only defined for Ad-Hoc builds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question goes into depth about how to create custom configurations and flags. Its not perfect but it works.

Still looking for an option that is more permanent and cross project compatible without having to spend time at the beginning of each project to set this up.

[iOS, detect ad-hoc from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252176/ios-detect-ad-hoc-from-code)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily set custom macros for each configuration in the build settings.

Comment: I am aware of custom macros, But I only see a Debug and a Release configuration. Am I going to have to create an Ad-Hoc configuration and manually change it in the Archive build scheme every time? If thats the case I might as well just have a hardcoded bool.

Comment: @Ryan: XCode doesn't let you define custom configurations?

Comment: It will let me define custom configurations I assume but I'm looking for a built in way to check if its an Ad Hoc build vs Store Build because this will be implemented across a lot of projects managed by different people.