# How to execute a specific function only in DEBUG and AdHoc modes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.3, ios5.1

What i would like to do is a simple button with an action method, This button is initialized, created, assigned to its action method and shown ONLY in Debug and AdHoc modes. So as a developer or tester, i can see the button, but in the release, the client won't be able to see that button.

What i did so far is the following:

-In my `project-->Build Settings` Tab, i set the Debug values to 1 in both Debug and Adhoc, like this:

[image]

-Then i opened up the prefix.pch file, and there, i am blocked and i don't know what to do.

Basically, my action method is something like this:

```
UIButton btnSwitch=[[UIButton alloc]init];

//Etc...
```

The above code should be called in a specific file (The UIViewController class which should contain the button).

How can i do that, i mean, how can i tell my application to execute that code in a specific file only in DEBUG and Adhoc modes.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: This link may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252176/ios-detect-ad-hoc-from-code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what your thinking with regards to the prefix.pch file is. Leave that alone for the moment.

You can create a button in code inside your view controller and do it conditionally like this.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btnSwitchImage"];

    btnSwitch = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    //frame size given as a point of reference only but when you create a button this
    //way you have to set the frame otherwise you will see nothing.
    btnSwitch.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
    [btnSwitch setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [btnSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:btnSwitch];
#endif
```

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap code up in guards:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    // Code here to only run when DEBUG is defined
#else
    // Code here to run only when DEBUG is not defined
#endif

// code here to execute regardless of the state of DEBUG
```

Also - if you are using Xcode 4 you don't need to define DEBUG yourself, it's done for you. You can control whether or not it is set by looking at the scheme.

The default Xcode scheme builds against Debug configuration which sets the debug flag. If you want to create an AdHoc scheme that sets this build flag, then add an AdHoc configuration based on the Debug configuration and then create a scheme based on that.

Comment: Hi, does this solution works for the `Adhoc` mode also ? if not, what `directive`should i mention? Thanx :)

Comment: As I said - create a new configuration called AdHoc based on the Debug Configuration, and then create a new scheme based on that.

Comment: Can you describe the steps please, where should i set the Adhoc, where is the Debug configuration?

Comment: In Swift `#ifdef` is now just `#if`. The directives remain the same.