# need Ad-hoc distribution app using development environment

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

My project is still in objective-c.

In my iOS project's info, in "**Preprocessor Macros**" section, I have defined:

```
Debug:   DEV_SERVER=1
Release: DEV_SERVER=0
```

In my source code I have:

```
#if DEV_SERVER
#define SERVER @"https://staging.myhost.com"
#else
#define SERVER @"https://myhost.com"
#endif
```

So, in release build I use production server, otherwise, using staging server.

The code communicating with backend create `NSURL` instance by:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:SERVER];
```

Everything works as expected.

But now, I would like to make an ad-hoc distribution to tester to test the app. I made the IPA file ready, but the ad-hoc distribution use production server. But we would like to use staging server for the ad-hoc distribution version app.

How to have the ad-hoc distribution app use staging server? Meanwhile, keep the distribution to Apple Store using production server? What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS, detect ad-hoc from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252176/ios-detect-ad-hoc-from-code)